# Ubuntu 12.10 gnome system monitor high cpu usage

Tags: 12.10, gnome, cpu, cpu-load

I am totally new to Ubuntu. I tried to install numerous times, but always removed it because of loud fan noise.
Me and my Bro have the same Notebook, a HP Compaq 615, and what grabbed my attention that no apps where running the fan was still loud, so i opend up system monitor and saw that the gnome system monitor and saw that the gnome system monitor uses a lot of cpu, the value jumped up and down for a few seconds, but after it always used 50-60% of my CPU, i think thats a bit pretty large.

Than another research, i saw that the video card is not detected, we have an **Ati Mobility Radeon HD 3200**, but i did not install it because, every time i tried to install back in time and reboot i was never able to log back in to Ubuntu because i got just a purple background and a bog saying Error.

So my question is, can this high CPU problem caused by that my Video Card is not detected?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that the Ubuntu installer you used may be corrupted, resulting to the unnatural behavior of the system.  The sure way to solve this is download another .iso or better get a torrent from the Ubuntu Gnome webpage, burn it again on DVD, install it again to your system, and see if it still misbehaves.  If it does, you may need another Ubuntu variant that doesn't require much system resources, i.e.: Lubuntu, Xubuntu, or even Bodhi Linux.  Go to http://www.distrowatch.com for the links. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Install `htop` in your system using

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

Now run `htop` from terminal. Usually the running processes are sorted in the oder of their cpu usage by default. If not change to sort by cpu usage. It'll look something like this.

[image]

Now you can find out the process that's hogging your cpu. Kill it or uninstall the software to prevent it from doing so.

Alternative you can use `top`

[image]